# Does a smaller application footprint mean cheaper PaaS costs? which language?

Tags: python, ruby, node.js, grails, cloud

So, I have built and deployed a Grails app onto cloudfoundry.

And as I play around with examining instances & memory I start to wonder;

If my app's footprint is larger because of the technology I chose to develop it in, will it start costing me money sooner rather than later? Surely it must?

If that is the case, am I better off developing in an alternative language? if so which has the smaller footprint (python, ruby, node.js)?

Of course, costs should not determine which language I use, I should select language/framework on merits and personal preference.

But it is still a question I'd would really like to know the answer to.

Comment: Development costs far outweigh PaaS operational costs in most cases. Build it first, and if required, make it cheaper second. Premature optimization applies to cost too, and that's exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Of those three, node.js has by far the more advanced interpreter courtesy of Javascript being fairly simple, and the massive resources browser vendors have committed towards interpreter development. That said, it's also new to the game, so the immaturity of available libraries might offset that. I'd say: prototype and benchmark. This will also let you make a call about ease of development.

Comment: To put some numbers behind willglynn's claims: A year of Amazon's "Web Application" sample costs ~$19,000. ALA's 2011 survey of web professionals had the most people answer their salary as between $40,000 and $60,000. Obviously this doesn't let us draw any conclusions about your situation, but it does make it not overly likely that your hosting costs will dominate development costs. (Unless your application very simple yet very resource-intensive. Or, obviously, unless you end up having a lot of users and need to scale.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rarely is memory footprint a concern when it comes to selecting a framework. If we were so concerned we'd be using hand-rolled assembly code with everything aggressively compressed into memory like some [demoscene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene) coder. This is obviously not the case.

Even Rails, which tends to be fairly heavy duty, will only use ~100MB per instance. With 512MB instances going for approximately $20 a month, the net cost of each instance ends up being on the order of $5 when accounting for OS overhead.

How many programmer hours does it take to end up costing you more than simply buying a system with greater capacity? Probably a lot unless your time is free.

Remember you can always lease your own hardware for a fraction of the cost of using a managed provider, where systems with 64GB of memory can be had for under $500/mo. In the end that barely pays for even a small share of a programmer per month.

I'd pay attention to how much a given developer can get done with the framework you choose. Some frameworks will work better for you, allowing you to execute better. Sometimes paying for extra memory is a way to offset sinking more time into development and optimization, things that are usually premature until you're dealing with server bills in the tens of thousands a month.

Comment: Good answer, but you're omitting the (admittedly not common) situation where you might need to scale because of the sheer number of users. Should your user base grow to the point where PaaS would cost more than a sysop team capable of managing your own hardware, you're essentially throwing money away.

Comment: You're presuming you can eliminate memory costs 100% which is never possible. A lot of the overhead comes from the type of data you're manipulating, not the language used to manipulate it, just as a lot of the performance issues in an application stem from the database and not the language interfacing with it. If you have *too many* users, you're on to something big, so either you're making money from subscriptions or advertising, or you should be seeking funding for developers. If you're somehow spending more money on hosting than developers, look for a better hosting provider.

Comment: Generally large-scale applications run out of CPU long before they run out of memory, though, and the reason you run out of CPU is because you're either not caching enough, or your implementation is inefficient. Both of these can usually be fixed once you know what the problem is, and it's rarely a simple case of "pay more money, add more memory".

Comment: Yup good answer, I am a little disturbed by your estimate of approx 100mb per running instance. My app, which doesn't do a great deal shows 600mb. Which is ultimately what got me thinking. Although I agree with the consensus, it is still a determining factor when selecting technology. If I write a dozen webapps over the next few years, with the intention of footing the bill for the deployments, then I might as well put my time and effort into a technology that will be both "suitable" and cheap to run

Comment: Cheap to run can be expensive to maintain, or so time-consuming to construct in the first place that it's not worth the effort. Don't forget that memory gets cheaper from year to year, where programming time does not. Never forget Moore's Law! I've never seen memory footprint be a deciding factor with anything that's not dealing with tens of millions of active users, and if that's the case, surely you can monetize your app enough to cover your costs.

Comment: For what it's worth, I manage about 50 different Rails applications with varying levels of activity on five 2GB Linode systems. That works out to an average of around $10/mo. per application for raw hosting costs. If you're doing customer work, *always* bundle in a hosting and support charge to be sure you're not getting killed on hosting costs.

Answer (score 0):

Memory footprint will certainly reflect on your PaaS expenses.
But to tell you what to use is hard without knowing more about the project.
Node.js per se is great, but it's not perfect for every case.
Python is very friendly for development, and has ok memory usage, but again - it all depends on what you're doing.